# Lightning & nextcloud: e-mail sheduling invitations for meetings&tasks

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, nextcloud, lightning

I can sucsessfully link my nextcloud-calendars with my lightning (thunderbird-calendar).
However, the integration with an e-mail address does not work properly.
When I create an event, and I want to invite other people to this event the following happens.
Although I choose "a@original.com" to be linked with a certain calender "cal" the organizer and sender of the invitation to an event of "cal" is not "a@original.com" but "b@othermailaddress.com"

b@othermailaddress.com is one of the many mailaddresses I have included in my thunderbird-profile.

**Anyone knows, how I can change to the e-mailaddress I actually chose in the specific calender settings?**

Comment: If you feel it is a bug then you need to report it. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en do not post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. The linked e-mailaddress b@othermailaddress.com is the one in your nexctcloud settings of your nextcloud user linked with your lightning-calendar.
[image: nextcloud settings screenshot]
////

the "prefer client-side email scheduling" checkbox is only *additional*. In my case it sent out the invitation e-mail twice, from both mailaddresses. So I unchecked it and went with the invitation function of my nextcloud.
[image: prefer client-side email scheduling" checkbox]

Sidenote: However, this is - from a security point of view - not the best solution, because the reciever gets to know an non required information: A possible username for a possible nextcloud.